# Event is causing an error, but I can't catch the exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, controls

A developer has created a custom control in ASP.NET using VB.NET.  The custom control uses a repeater.  In certain scenarios, the rpt_ItemDataBound event is encountering a data error.  My goal is rather than having the user see the yellow screen of death, give the user a friendlier error explaining exactly what the data error is.  I figured I would be able to use a Try/Catch block as shown below throw the exception, however, it appears that the event has nowhere to be thrown to and stops executing at the "End Try" line.

```
Protected Sub rpt_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rpt1.ItemDataBound, rpt2.ItemDataBound

    Try

        ProcessBadData...

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try

End Sub
```

In VB.NET, I can find where the repeater's DataSource is being set, however, I can not find a DataBind event.

Any ideas how I can capture the exception in this ASCX control so I can report it to the user?

**Edit:**

The stack trace looks like this.  There is another repeater within the repeater that is actually causing the error (rptOther) and I'm able to catch the error, but I can only throw it to the rpt_ItemDataBound.  I can't figure out how rpt_ItemDataBound is getting called without a DataBind event.

```
at Company.WebForms.Control.rptOther_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnItemDataBound(RepeaterItemEventArgs e)    
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem)    
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource)    
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)    
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.DataBind()    
at Company.WebForms.Control.rpt_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried registering a global exception handler? If you can catch the exception there you can use the stack trace to pinpoint where you might try to catch it properly.

Comment: Hadn't thought to look in the exception's StackTrace.  Thanks for the idea.